# How to prevent TinyMCE from inserting &nbsp; into empty elements without changing initialization code

Tags: html, tinymce

In some CMS I need to have some text that starts with an empty html element.

```
<div class="invisible-div"></div>
<p>Some text</p>
```

The text is entered through **TinyMCE**. However **TinyMCE** automatically puts `&nbsp;` into empty elements.

```
<div class="invisible-div">&nbsp;</div>
<p>Some text</p>
```

Normally I would just change the way **TinyMCE** is initialized to prevent this behavior, but in this case I'm just the user of the CMS, so I can't change the code. Even so, can I still have my empty element in the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out I can trick **TinyMCE** into thinking that an element isn't empty, by inserting a html comment inside it.

```
<div class="invisible-div"><!-- this is empty --></div>
<p>Some text</p>
```